# hash_hmac and bin2hex in Python3

Tags: php, python-3.x, cryptography

I was given the `PHP` code related to cryptographic function which make use of `hash_mac` and `bin2hex`.  The logic is simple. I have to digest my `key` and then convert the binary to hex string that's all

Here is my `PHP`

```
$reqBody = '{
            "citizenNo":"9990601821487",
            "birthDate":"2520-02-24"
            }'; // Put JSON body into reqBody parameter
$obj = json_decode($reqBody,true);
$transformBody = json_encode($obj); // Convert JSON into string without any whitespace
$secret = "idkfaiddqd";
$hashmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $transformBody, $secret, true);
$signature = bin2hex(hash_hmac('sha256', $transformBody, $secret, true)); 

echo "X-API-key : ",$signature,"n";
```

`PHP`: `28d28fd2cecc10a5d1e98a03dbec23844780d1609e7eaedba72e7c3a8e0e84e1n`

I implement `Python` version

```
        SECRET = "idkfaiddqd"
        data = {
            "citizenNo": "9990601821487",
            "birthDate": "2520-02-24",
        }
        transform_body = str(data).replace(' ', '')
        aaa = hmac.new(bytes(SECRET, 'utf-8'), transform_body.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

`Python`: `2e3dff89bef78489c4f42e1e54a40b257e908aaa2d1aa46b5873acb53c51c9ac`

**Question:**
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the `transform_body` string.

When you look at the PHP string you can see this:

```php
{"citizenNo":"9990601821487","birthDate":"2520-02-24"}
```

The python string looks like this:

```py
{'citizenNo':'9990601821487','birthDate':'2520-02-24'}
```

Do you see the difference? Python uses single quotation marks, PHP normal quotation marks.

To make the python script work exactly as the PHP script you have to replace to single quotation marks in the python version with normal quotation marks.

```py
import hmac
import hashlib
SECRET = "idkfaiddqd"
data = {
  "citizenNo": "9990601821487",
  "birthDate": "2520-02-24",
}
transform_body = str(data).replace(' ', '')
transform_body = transform_body.replace('\'', '"')
aaa = hmac.new(SECRET.encode(), transform_body.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
print(aaa)
```

Output:

```py
28d28fd2cecc10a5d1e98a03dbec23844780d1609e7eaedba72e7c3a8e0e84e1
```

And you have an extra "n" in the output of your php script. I guess that was supposed to be a `\n`?